# Changing date format from YY WW to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe which look something like this

```
co_code   company_name   year   week   returns
1          A             2008    40     0.45
1          A             2008    41     0.33
1          A             2008    42     0.31
.
.
.
2          B             2002    01     0.22
2          B             2002    02     0.32
.
.
.
```

And so on. Years and week differs from company to company.

I want a separate column which replaces year and week into date. Here date should be last day of the week

Output should look something like this

```
co_code   company_name   date        returns
1          A             2008-10-11    0.45
1          A             2008-10-18    0.33
1          A             2008-10-25    0.31
.
.
.
2          B             2002-01-07    0.22
2          B             2002-01-14    0.32
```

Note:- This change should not affect ordering of dataframe. Rows should not get disturbed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,date:=as.Date(paste(year, week, 6, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")]
```

**Output-**

```
co_code company_name year week returns       date
1:       1            A 2008   40    0.45 2008-10-11
2:       1            A 2008   41    0.33 2008-10-18
3:       1            A 2008   42    0.31 2008-10-25
```

**Input data-**

```
dt <- read.table(text="co_code   company_name   year   week   returns
1          A             2008    40     0.45
1          A             2008    41     0.33
1          A             2008    42     0.31",header=T)
```

**Note**- I have used `6th` day of a week to match desired output. But, we can change that to whatever we required.

Comment: Why use 6 here?!

Comment: to match his desired output

Comment: we can change to what ever day of week we want.

Comment: Agree but seems weird for a week to start on Saturday. Perhaps data specific.

Comment: Yes. I agree. Indeed, I followed desired output.

Comment: Also, I have added note for more clarification.